# I could tell (that)/I could see that

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> A: I didn't expect you to show up this morning.
>
> B: (smiling) No, **I could tell**. I hope it was a good surprise.
>
> A: Are you kidding me? You don't know how much I've missed you.

Would "I could tell" be correct here to mean "I could see that"? And I wouldn't need to add "that" to it, would I?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be correct. In this case, it would be inappropriate to add “that,” because then you’d have to further specify exactly what you were able to tell, and that would likely end up being redundant.